# Nativescript Tabs: Want to route to templates/compts that are not tabs

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a 4 tabbed app and am trying to route to other pages that aren't one of the tabs.

For example I want to link to a form in QuicksnapComponent. First I had the routing out in app.routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { LoginComponent  } from "./login/login.component";

import { QuicksnapComponent } from "./quicksnap/quicksnap.component";
...
import * as app from 'tns-core-modules/application';
import { TabView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view";

export const COMPONENTS = [
    ...
    QuicksnapComponent, 
    ...];

export const ROUTES: Routes = [

    { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },

    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },

    { path: "quicksnap", component: QuicksnapComponent },
    {
        path: "tabs",
        loadChildren: () => import("~/tabs/tabs.module").then(m => m.TabsModule)
    },         
];
...
```

tabs.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule, NSEmptyOutletComponent } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { TabsComponent } from "./tabs.component";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: "default", component: TabsComponent, children: [

                    {
                        path: "home",
                        outlet: "homeTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/home/home.module").then(m => m.HomeModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: "expense",
                        outlet: "expenseTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/expense/expense.module").then(m => m.ExpenseModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: "journey",
                        outlet: "journeyTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/journey/journey.module").then(m => m.JourneyModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: "reports",
                        outlet: "reportsTab",
                        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                        loadChildren: () => import("~/reports/reports.module").then(m => m.ReportsModule),
                    }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        TabsComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class TabsModule { }
```

I have a link from HomeComponent:

```
      <StackLayout class="expenseStackLayout">
          <GridLayout class="home gradbg" rows="auto, *" (tap)="navigateToPage('./quicksnap')">
            <Label row="0"  text="Quicksnap Receipt"  class="homeItemTitle"></Label>
            <Label row="1"  text="Store a photo of a receipt" class="homeItemText"></Label>
          </GridLayout>        
      </StackLayout>
```

```
    navigateToPage(page: string) {
        this.routerExt.navigate([page]);
    }
```

When I do it this way it does bring up the Quicksnap form BUT there is no ActionBar on top and there are no tabs along the bottom.

Is there a way to show these?

I tried a different tack and moved the route to QuicksnapComponent into home.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { QuicksnapComponent } from "../quicksnap/quicksnap.component";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([
            { path: "", redirectTo: "home" },
            { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
            { path: "quicksnap", component: QuicksnapComponent }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        QuicksnapComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I then was brought to a white page with the tabs along the bottom as soon as I logged in (should have been re-directed to HomeComponent).

I n the console there were error message complaining about the form validation I have in QuicksnapComponent. OK I got rid of the form validation and then I was loggin in and getting sent to HomeComponent but when clicking on the link getting console errors like:

```
S: ### ErrorHandler Error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quicksnap'
JS: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quicksnap'
JS:     at ApplyRedirects.push.../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (file:///node_modules\@angular\router\fesm5\router.js:2464:0) [angular]
JS:     at CatchSubscriber.selector (file:///node_modules\@angular\router\fesm5\router.js:2445:0) [angular]
JS:     at CatchSubscriber.push.../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (file:///node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\operators\catchError.js:34:0) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber.push.../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (file:///node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\Subscriber.js:79:0) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber.push.../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (file:///node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\Subscriber.js:59:0) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber....
JS: ### ErrorHandler Stack: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quicksnap'
JS: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'quicksnap'
JS:     at ApplyRedirects.push.../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (file:///node_modules\@angular\router\fesm5\router.js:2464:0) [angular]
JS:     at CatchSubscriber.selector (file:///node_modules\@angular\router\fesm5\router.js:2445:0) [angular]
JS:     at CatchSubscriber.push.../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (file:///node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\operators\catchError.js:34:0) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber.push.../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (file:///node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\Subscriber.js:79:0) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber.push.../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (file:///node_modules\rxjs\_esm5\internal\Subscriber.js:59:0) [angular]
JS:     at MapSubscriber....
```

Any ideas how I can navigate to pages like this and also preserve the ActionBar on top and tabs on bottom?

TIA!

Comment: You may find additional help here: https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng

Comment: Thanks @Tim, yes, I have been working from that demo but still having the issue with pages that aren't tabs displaying with no tabstrip.

Comment: Or another way of phrasing the question might be: How does one route to a page not specified in tabs.module.ts while preserving the TabStrip and ActionBar?